# how to replace a char with '*' at odd index else with '+'

Tags: java, replace, indexof

i want to replace s char with '+' if it is at the odd index else with '*'
Here is my code

```
//calling emphasize(shanuss,s)
//expected output +hanu*+
public static String emphasize(String phrase ,char ch) {
        String l = phrase;
        char c = ch;
        int s = l.indexOf(c);

        while (s >= 0) {
            if(s%2==0)
            { l=l.replace(l.charAt(s),'+');}
            else{l=l.replace(l.charAt(s),'*');}
            s = l.indexOf(c, s + 1);
        }

        return l;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: just loop and create a new string

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier to work with a `char[]` than with a `String`, because a `String` is immutable, which means you'd have to keep creating new `String` objects.  Start by converting to a `char[]`, then iterate through that.

```
public static String emphasize(String phrase, char toReplace) {
    char[] characters = phrase.toCharArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < characters.length; index++ ) {
        if (characters[index] == toReplace) {
            characters[index] = index % 2 == 1 ? '+' : '*';
        }
    }
    return new String(characters);
}
```

Comment: An alternative to this loop would be to use `indexOf` to find the next occurrence. Very little between the two, though.

Comment: @AndyTurner If you write an answer like what you describe, then I will upvote it (assuming you don't mess it up).

Comment: @AndyTurner You seem to have changed my answer completely.  I'm not sure why.  Did you mean to write your own?

Comment: Ah, dammit. The app got confused when I tried to edit your answer to grab the source. Please roll back.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [@Dawood answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790870/3733369) would be using strings (as you are doing atm), but you need to create another string to return (immutable property)

The algoritm would be:

1. For any element in the phrase.
2. check if pair iteration and equals to char to be replaced. if true, add an "+" to the output string.
3. check if odd iteration and equals to char to be replaced. if true, add an "*" to the output string.
4. if not s, just add the input char to the output string.

### emphasize method:

```
public class TestEmphasize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(emphasize("shanuss",'s'));
    }

    public static String emphasize(String phrase ,char ch) {
        int s = phrase.indexOf(ch);
        String output = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            if(s%2 == 0 && s == i) output += "+";
            if(s%2 != 0 && s == i) output += "*";
            else if(phrase.charAt(i) != ch) output += phrase.charAt(i); 
            s = phrase.indexOf(ch, s + 1);
        }

        return output;
    }

}
```

### Output:

```
+hanu*+
```

---

### Extra:

If you still want to use your original code, you should use `replaceFirst(String regex,String replacement)`, because `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` method will change all occurrences of `s` to `+`, leading to unexpected behavior.

```
l=l.replaceFirst(l.charAt(s)+"",'+'+"");
```

*note*: the `+ ""` is a trick to convert `char` to `String`

Comment: could you please tell me what's the problem with my code. at loop it terminating after if statement.

Comment: replace method returns a string resulting from replacing **ALL** occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar. So, in you code in the first if statement, all your `s` will be replaced with `+`, finishing the while loop because there are no more `s` occurences.

Comment: @ShanuReddy check my edit. you should change just one line of code to your original source code.